# How to modify a DLL to ignore unused dependencies?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, dll, gd

I had to download a different version from a DLL, but now this new version requires 4 other DLLs, which I don't want to add into my package. Since I'm not even using them, it would be a waste of space.

Is it somehow possible to edit the DLL and make it ignore the missing dependencies which aren't even used?

I'm talking about `libgd2.dll`, and since the website is down, I was unable to find the old version of this library, so I had to download this newer version. Earlier I had `bgd.dll`, but now I can't find the old `bgd.lib` file anywhere on the web.

Comment: You *are* using the dependencies, just indirectly. Who are you to say what `libgd2.dll` needs and what it doesn't?

Comment: because i know it doesnt need PNG library if i only use JPG library?

Comment: It's called **dependencies** for a reason...

Comment: @Rookie: you don't know that. Sure you might think intuitively that it only uses libpng for PNG-only features. But maybe it uses utility functions from it. Or maybe it makes *any* calls into it, which you should not deny it.

Comment: okay, so youre saying someone made a DLL that requires PNG, font, ico and zip libraries just to make JPG saving working? ok ok... suggestions to get smaller JPG library then perhaps?

Comment: The GD graphics library is open source, so get the source code and compile the parts you want directly into your application.  On the other hand the readme for GD says it uses the JPEG library (http://www.ijg.org/) so perhaps that is all you need.

Comment: @harry, i dont know how to compile the ijg library, help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375789/how-to-build-this-project-jpeg-lib