# Simple JPG library (dll) only for saving a JPG image?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, dll, jpeg

Has anyone made a simple DLL for Windows, so i can just save raw image data into JPG format? It should have the .lib and .h files as well so i dont need to mess with the sources compiling since i have found it to be very hard.

Some point to take into account:

- I cant compile libjpeg (ijg.org), i cant find binaries for it (dll/.lib/.h)
- GD library website is down, and the new version requires PNG dll's etc even for JPG saving.
- I dont want to use Windows internal JPG functions since i want to be able to run it on linux too.

**Edit:**
I am trying to find as small library as possible: just writing a JPG (or reading too, if only a writing lib doesnt exist).

Comment: Maybe this is helpful to you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457370/c-how-to-convert-bitmap-byte-array-to-jpeg-format

Comment: @ulvund, this is c++ project, not c#/.net

Comment: Shouldn't this question be "how do I build libjpeg"?  libjpeg will do what you need...

Comment: @AshleysBrain, i posted a question like that already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375789/how-to-build-this-project-jpeg-lib but since it seems nobody knows answer, i thought of switching the library instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [jpeg-compressor](http://code.google.com/p/jpeg-compressor/), I think that it's the most simple one.

Comment: Wow, exactly what im looking for! i'll see if i can make it work.

Comment: BIG THANKS! it was everything i needed. Damn. amazing.

Comment: @Rookie: You can also use GDI+ (see my other answer) - saving JPEG files is built into Windows.

Comment: @Larry, i know, but it wont work on linux then (as i said in my question).

Comment: this thing took only 15KB space in my exe, just amazing.

Comment: Your question was tagged Windows and not Linux and your question asks for a Windows DLL.  You're right, I missed the "since i want to be able to run it on linux too."

Comment: damn, too bad this compressor has to be 1.5x slower than my previous library... i didnt know there can be such a huge performance differences, well, i guess i need to stick with this anyways. or maybe i messed it up myself... gotta check.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) ?

Comment: I have not, i will look at it :)

Comment: damn, that is huge library; i was thinking of something that has only the JPG writing, i dont need PNG or anything else.

Comment: @Rookie, does it matter that it is a huge library?  I admit, it does far more than what you're looking for.  Is space an issue?

Comment: yes it does, the point was to find just JPG saving (or with loading as well) library, because i want to minimize the size of executables. atm i have 300KB library for saving JPG (using the old GDlib), but i lost my .lib/.h files so i cant compile my project anymore! i dont want to replace that tiny library with 2.8megabyte library, when my whole project takes around 1megabyte in total...

Comment: I know what you've said about huge libraries, but what about DevIL? It seems to be a little smaller. Ultimately, to strip *any* solution down, you're going to need to reconfigure and recompile it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use GDI+?  It's built into Windows so you don't need to add any additional libraries.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533844%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) page shows an example of loading a bitmap image from a file on disk and saving it as a JPEG file (with different levels of encoding quality).